# How to install Docker on Rhel 9?

Tags: docker, oracle-linux

I am using Oracle Linux 9 and I would like to install Docker. I checked this website: *https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/linux-install/* for instructions but it seems that there are instructions only for Fedora. Will these instructions for Fedora work on Rhel 9 or do I have to use a different method? And if yes, where can I find the appropriate instructions?

Comment: You can follow this site: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/rhel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Instructions for CentOS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/), as this is also compatible and closer to RHEL and thus to Oracle Linux than fedora.

The Instructions for RHEL are not working, because the RHEL instructions are for IBM Z CPU architecture. [image: screenshot of docker documentation, rhel instructions, stating that only working on IBM Z architecture]